# Designing the software and Architecture of the software subtasks

Tags: architecture, uml, project, diagram, software-design

I'm new in this field and I'm trying to create a project design. as two milestones, I've defined

1. The architecture of the software
2. Designing the software

and as the subtasks/ activities, I've considered

1. The architecture of the software

Creating the component diagram

2. Designing the software

Creating Behavioral UML Diagram

Creating Structural UML Diagram

Is it correct?

Comment: No. There are books taking some meters in the shelf talking about that. Take one and start reading.

Answer (score 2):

This sequential approach sounds very theoretical. In practice, architecture and design are linked and the architecture emerges in the early stage of the work as the design progresses.

This being said, the [system theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_theory) defines a system to have a boundary with its environment, to be made of parts in interaction to achieve the system's goals. From an architectural point of view,  the main parts are called usually "components", when they are well defined and self-standing.

In a classic UML view, you would first start to define the boundaries and the goals of the system, with a [use-case diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html). Because all the rest has not meaning without this core understanding.

Then indeed you'd identify and model main [components](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html), then break down the components into smaller components, and so on,  until you get to some detailed [class diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html). The bridge between components and classes is the [composite structure](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composite-structure-diagrams.html).  In the same time, at each level, you would also design the interactions between the components or the objects of different classes, as well as other behavioral aspects.

In the early thinking about a system, it is however not always easy to be as precise and accurate as UML requires.  Representing for example a web architecture with some components on the client, and a bunch of services on the server is not easy to express simply in UML.  This is why, more and more, alternative lighter modelling approaches are used, such as for example the [C4 model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4_model):  C4 allows to have a less formal high level vision on the architecture, that is easily and quickly reengineered, and when it's stable enough, you may consider to dig down further in UML.